# How can I detect a file's encoding?

Tags: go

I'm trying figure out the encoding of a file on Windows using Go. Doing some research, I've found many recommendations for Mozilla's [Charset Detectors](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/intl/chardet.html) (chardet), but they're hard to compile, and I'm not having any luck.

I've also found libguess, and it seems is widely used in Linux, but I can't make it work in Windows.

What's the best way to go about this? Is there a de-facto standard library to use with Go on Windows?

Comment: Actually, don't expect too much (there is a reason why libguess is named lib*guess*). I highly recommend this article: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `python` package: [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet).

Comment: The tarball contains some character frequency tables, so the statistical approach seems to be a standard. In the worst case it should be easy to dig out the frequency tables and write a custom solution.

Comment: Maybe I could port this package to Go if I cannot find any ready to use one.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [Enca](http://gitorious.org/enca), Extremely Naive Charset Analyzer. I guess you could try to read the file using all candidate encodings and compute how far each of the attempts is from a “standard” character frequency distribution for the language. Enca requires some language info, but I’m not sure if it uses this approach. (It’s just an idea, it might be horribly misguided.)

Comment: Thanks to share this lib! I will check it out.

Comment: I got enca.exe after make, can it be compiled to *.lib or *.dll?

Comment: There’s a library target in the distribution, but I have no idea how to create a DLL.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use this [library](https://github.com/saintfish/chardet)  to detect the encoding of your string by reading them in bytes.

Here is the sample code in Go.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "github.com/saintfish/chardet"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func main() {
    dat, err := os.ReadFile("/Users/yourname/Downloads/456")
    check(err)
    detector := chardet.NewTextDetector()
    result, err := detector.DetectBest(dat)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("Detected charset is %s", result.Charset)
    }
}
```

Output will be like

> Detected charset is ISO-8859-1